# Monitor goes black

Tags: monitor

Just installed 14.04 on my computer and after I solved my core-heating-problem, the new problem is that after 1 minute on desktop, either doing things or not - the monitor goes black.. 
No time to check properties and stuff.. 
I changed the monitor itself and even the graphics card - didn't help..

**I want to make it clear, the computer itself is still running when this annoying thing happens..**
at first I downloaded Psensor to see the temperature of the cpu..
After everything was good, the computer turned itself off (because over-heating-on-purpose, to check the cpu temperature behaviour). After that my monitor problem began.

Comment: Have you tried to connect the monitor to another PC? Maybe it's a hardware issue of monitor.

Comment: I did'nt try, but I took another monitor and it happens with it too

Answer (score 0):

I bet you didn't solve the overheating problem although you think you did. System gets too hot, thermal protection gets triggered, system powers down and monitor goes black.

Comment: Well, one of the first things I did is to install Psensor and I managed to see that the temperature of the cpu is like it should be (45 - 60 c).. Furthermore, I wrote that the computer itself is still working when the monitor goes black.. fans and leds etc..

Comment: OK then it must be something else. How about the temperature of the GPU which can be a bigger heat producer than the CPU? In terminal execute the command sensors and please show the output, so edit your question and include the output in it.

Comment: Sorry I comment after long time..
I have no way to check the GPU's temp'..
I'll try to operate with another computer (same motherboard), I'll switch the GPU's and the hard-discs and hope it'll be ok :)

Comment: Good luck and please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Well everything is fine! With the GPU and hard discs from the problematic computer,  but dual core of the other computer and it's power supply..